# How to test solana token name and logo on devnet

Tags: token, solana

I have made a successful pull request but cant see the name and token icon updated. Any idea how long would it take ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's updated immediately on the repo, but most dapps that use the token list, such as wallets and dexes, only update the token-list every other week, so it may take a moment for the change to reflected in wallets and apps.